# Gulp is not creating new directories

Tags: gulp

I'm new to gulp, and I have a very basic question.

I've used the code snippet below to copy an "html" file to another directory.

```
gulp.task('copy-html', (done) => {
    return gulp.src('./index.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
})
```

Then in the command line I wrote and executed `gulp copy-html`

I was expecting to see a `dist` folder with `index.html` in it.

but what happens is that nothing happens. The Task completes but no changes occur.

```
Node version: 9.3.0
npm version : 5.5.1
gulp versions:
    CLI version 2.0.1
    Local version 4.0.0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure but can you try to add a relative _path_ to your `gulp.dest()` task? like so `path.join(__dirname, 'dist')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what worked for me. I just moved the solution directory to the hard disk partition where the os is installed and it worked like a charm